# Trying to update select list options from a jQuery post results

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, json, razor

I have the following Dropdown on my View...

```
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, new SelectList(new List<string>(), ""), "Select ...")
</div>
```

My controller contains the following action method that I am calling to update the options...

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetCategories(int ChallengeId, string Gender, DateTime BirthDate)
    {
        CategoriesContext db = new CategoriesContext();
        ChallengesContext cc = new ChallengesContext();
        Challenge challenge = cc.Challenges.Where(c => c.ChallengeId == ChallengeId).Single();
        var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.GenderOption == Gender && c.SponsorId == challenge.SponsorId).AsEnumerable()
                                      .Select(s => new SelectListItem { Text = s.CategoryName, Value = s.CategoryId.ToString() }).ToList();

        SelectList list = new SelectList(categories);
        return Json(list);
    }
```

I call the following function when another item on the page changes:

```
function GetCategories() {
  var _challengeid = $('#ChallengeId').val();
  var _gender = $('#Gender').val();
  var _birthdate = $('#Birthdate').val();

  if (_birthdate != "" && _gender != "" && _challengeid > 0) {
    $('html,body').css('cursor', 'wait');
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetCategories", "Coach")';
    $.post(url, { ChallengeId: _challengeid, Gender: _gender, BirthDate: _birthdate }, function (data) {
      $("#CategoryId").empty();
      $.each(data, function (index, val) {
        $('#CategoryId')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", val.Text)
          .text(val.Text));
      });
      $('html,body').css('cursor', 'auto');
    }, "json");
  }
```

The dropdown items are just full of "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem".  I am getting all of my items, but something is not right in either the transfer of my items from the Action Method or the way that I am grabbing them in my javascript.  Can anyone point out what my issue is?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is really no reason why you should wrap the JSON around a `SelectList`.

```
var categories = db.Categories.Where(c => c.GenderOption == Gender && c.SponsorId == challenge.SponsorId)
    .Select(s => new { Text = s.CategoryName, Value = s.CategoryId.ToString() });
return Json(categories);
```

Check with the debugger in the browser, the `data` response should be a JSON.

Comment: So instead of returning ActionResult, return JsonResult?

Comment: Yes, it just needs to be a plain old JSON not SelectItem